# Which WiFi adapter is best for the raspberry pi

Tags: wifi

I am looking for a WiFi adapter for my raspberry pi and need one with a good monitor mode, which one would be best

Comment: Which model of Raspberry Pi do you have?

Comment: Hello and welcome -- I have not tested but you can patch the built-in Wifi adapter of raspberry pi by [nexmon](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon). -- "*Nexmon is our C-based firmware patching framework for Broadcom/Cypress WiFi chips that enables you to write your own firmware patches, for example, to enable monitor mode with radiotap headers and frame injection.*" -- A better [installation](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/enable-monitor-mode-packet-injection-raspberry-pi-0189378/).

Comment: @Dougie raspberry pi 3 B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch the built-in Wifi adapter of raspberry pi by Nexmon:

> Nexmon is our C-based firmware patching framework for Broadcom/Cypress
>   WiFi chips that enable you to write your own firmware patches, for
>   example, to enable monitor mode with radiotap headers and frame
>   injection.

- [GitHub source.](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon)
- [Another good installation.](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/enable-monitor-mode-packet-injection-raspberry-pi-0189378/)

---

If you want to buy a wireless adapter that supported "monitor mode" and "packet injection", there is plenty of choices.

At first, check [this link](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) out to check the list of USB wireless adapter that supported by raspberry pi.

You can choose something like [ALFA AWUS036NEH](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0035OCVO6). Just search your favored one.